# How can I define rewrite rule to accept also empty string in addition to a-zA-Z-?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using rewrite rules in a htaccess to define particular strings which, when placed in an url opens specific pages.

e.g. in this case category name and product name

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)$        /products.php?kat_name=$1&prod_name=$2
```

So when given URL is e.g. `/products/shirts/t-shirt` everything works fine. But when URL is `/products//t-shirt`, the rule doesn't work, because of empty string after the first slash.

How can I modify my rule to accept also empty pattern after the first slash?

Sorry I'm not very familliar with rewrite rules.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: What should be `kat_name` for `/products//t-shirt` ?

Comment: kat_name could stay empty. So in that case, no kat_name is given. The second parameter (prod_name) is mandatory. The first one is optional. Normally we always have also the first parameter. But on product search or in rare cases, it could be left empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now found a better solution on the web myself by using the * operator instead the +

This allows also to leave the value empty:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z-]*)/([a-zA-Z-]+)$        /products.php?kat_name=$1&prod_name=$2
```

Comment: Wish you had tested it before posting it. This will give nice 404

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of optional matching in a non-capture group:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^products/(?:([a-z-]+)/)?([a-z-]+)/?$ products.php?kat_name=$1&prod_name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will following matches:

- `/products/shirts/t-shirt => $_GET`:

```sh
    [kat_name] => shirts
    [prod_name] => t-shirt
```

- `/products//t-shirt => $_GET`:

```sh
    [kat_name] => 
    [prod_name] => t-shirt
```

Comment: Ok, I see, maybe I made an error in explanation. From your two examples the second would look like this /products//t-shirt - so two slashes before t-shirt (empty between slashes)

Comment: `http://example.com/products//t-shirt` would produce same result, please test because multiple `/`s are converted into a single `/` in `RewriteRule` pattern.